# python write to file if the file already exist

Tags: python, split

so i wrote a code to split a file(x) into multiple file(y), what if (y) already exist, how do i combine the new file with existing file

here are my current code:

```
with open('large.dat, encoding='utf-8') as infile, open ('small.dat', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if '462888' in line:
            outfile.write(line)
```

...

also i want to combine the content from new and existing file without having spaces between them

Comment: You can open a file for writing (appending if it exists) by passing "a" as the mode argument to open

Answer (score 0):

Open `y` in `a` or append mode, if it doesn't exist it will create it, if it does it will add data to it.

```
with open("y", "a") as file:
    file.write("hello world\n")
```

Comment: is it possible to ignore the write if the new content is the same as in (y)?

Comment: you could use an ```if``` statement, but it would be easier to just write a couple line breaks between the original and the appended text, so you could go back through and see the differences. Or, you could write to a new file, and keep (y) as the original.